# How to fast track branch after pull request in Github

Tags: git, github

Not sure if this is the place to ask questions about Github.

I have forked a public repo and added two commits to it, then sent to the original author asking for a pull request. The author have complied with the request and now I'd wish to fast track my own repo to the HEAD of the author's repo. All of my new commits are in the author's repo now, so there aren't any side-tracked commits (what's the proper name for this btw? I thought it was fork but that sounded weird considering how Github refer to forks.).

Thanks!

Comment: Could I please ask what's the reason for downvote? Is it because it's asked in the wrong place? If that's case, can someone let me know where is a good place to ask these types of questions as I couldn't find an official Github forum. Thanks!

Comment: No idea for the downvote. +1 from me. This is a valid question amongst the 2312 questions about GitHub already there on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [GitHub help page for fork](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/), the best policy here is to:

- define a remote called upstream and pointing to the original repo (the one where the author accepted your pull request)
- pull from that upstream repo

#### Pull in upstream changes

> If the original repo you forked your project from gets updated, you can add those updates to your fork by running the following code:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
```

Or you could, after the fetch, reset your `master` branch to `upstream/master`, in order to have the exact same history.

So, when you fork a repo, and clone that forked repo to your workstation:

- remote 'origin' refers to your fork
- remote 'upstream' refers to the original repo that your forked. You need to explicitly add that remote reference to your repo.